# How to Integrate matlab with Qt on windows 7

Tags: c++, qt, matlab, qt4

I'm stuck in a very important part of my project as i need to call Matlab functions form Qt 4.7.3 since i use the Qt for my interface (UI) and i want to call matlab function that return results and it appears on Qt UI

i searched many and many and i didn't find any thing that can help even with traditional C++

Comment: Qt isn't a language; it's a library. You still write mostly C++ code, especially for all the non-Qt stuff.

Comment: so do you have a way to call matlab functions from C++ code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/DLL/MatlabSharedLib.aspx) will get you started. Basically you compile a dll from within Matlab, and call the dll from your c++ code. Note however: it can take a looong time to load the dll since it loads the matlab runtime etc. Also, all computers you want to use it on need the matlab runtime installed.

A newer option is [this one](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab-coder/?s_cid=global_nav). Haven't tried it yet so I cannot comment on it but it looks promising.

Answer (score 1):

See [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_external/f38569.html) for calling Matlab from C++. You'll need to visualize the results yourself, if you want to visualize them in Qt.

Comment: Is there no way to use e.g. matlab's plotting capabilities in Qt or maybe java? thanks.  I find matlab's plotting to be very useful and would love to see that hooked in to a Qt view.